# How to start and stop a function

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a go function `processing` that use two distinct goroutines. `produce` will push some data into a channel and `consume` will read these data. Here is an example:

```
type MyObject struct{
    ...
}

func processing() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    dataChannel := make(chan MyObject, 5)

    wg.Add(2)

    go produce(wg, dataChannel)
    go consume(wg, dataChannel)

    wg.Wait()
}

func produce (wg *sync.WaitGroup, dataChannel chan MyObject){
    for{
        // Produce data in dataChannel
    }
}

func consume (wg *sync.WaitGroup, dataChannel chan MyObject){
    for{
        // Consume data from dataChannel
    }
}
```

I want my `processing` function to be started and stoped by an HTTP call. So I am looking to do something as follow:

```
func main() {

    // echo instance
    e := echo.New()
    e.GET("/", startProcessing)
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8099"))
}

func startProcessing(c echo.Context) error{

    command := c.QueryParam("command")

    if(command == "start"){
        processing()
    }else if(command == "stop"){
        if (/* ? processing is running ? */){
            /* ? stop processing process? */
        }
    }       
}
```

What is the correct way to do this with Go?

Comment: The question is bit broad. But the answer is simple: Provide a context.Context to both produce and consume when started and make them stop if the context is done. Then stop your context in the stop command.

Comment: You also need to keep track of started processes and specify which one to stop, or do you intend the stop-command to stop all started processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how to start and stop a function using context, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/FI0HQt5IHQv):

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    dataChannel := make(chan MyObject, 5)
    wg.Add(2)
    go produce(ctx, &wg, dataChannel)
    go consume(&wg, dataChannel)

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    cancel() // cancel when we are finished consuming data

    wg.Wait()
}

func produce(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup, dataChannel chan MyObject) {
    defer wg.Done()
    i := 1
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            close(dataChannel)
            return // returning not to leak the goroutine
        case dataChannel <- MyObject{i}:
            i++
            time.Sleep(250 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}

func consume(wg *sync.WaitGroup, dataChannel chan MyObject) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for v := range dataChannel {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}

type MyObject struct {
    i int
}
```

---

For HTTP you need to do it yourself!
It needs to have some **concurrent safe** ID or map or something to keep track of how many functions you called and then call a `cancel()` to stop it.